# Vercel deployment error: npm run build exited with 126

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vite, vercel

I've made a project using Vite & Vue.js pushed it to github, but when I wanted to deploy it to vercel app it shows this error:

```
[09:02:23.126] Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1
[09:02:23.266] Cloning github.com/Zein-MB/Age-calulator-app (Branch: master, Commit: 547a770)
[09:02:23.281] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[09:02:24.636] Cloning completed: 1.369s
[09:02:25.050] Running "vercel build"
[09:02:25.713] Vercel CLI 32.1.0
[09:02:26.411] Installing dependencies...
[09:02:27.132] 
[09:02:27.133] up to date in 254ms
[09:02:27.133] 
[09:02:27.133] 3 packages are looking for funding
[09:02:27.133]   run `npm fund` for details
[09:02:27.145] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[09:02:27.145] Running "npm run build"
[09:02:27.546] 
[09:02:27.546] > age-calculator-app@0.0.0 build
[09:02:27.546] > vite build
[09:02:27.546] 
[09:02:27.555] sh: /vercel/path0/node_modules/.bin/vite: Permission denied
[09:02:27.576] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126
```

Comment: How are you deploying it to vercel? From your local or through some CI?

Comment: @RobinThomas from local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `126` means that, bash doesn't have permission to execute the `vite` binary.

You can fix that by:

```
sudo chmod +x node_modules/.bin/vite
```

---

If the above didn't work, a fresh install of the `node_modules` might help.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm ci
```

Comment: is there a possibility to change folder/files permissions on vercel server for nextjs 13 project?